# Using Windows API DrawText with DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to use the Windows API function [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but don't get the results I expect. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but as I read the documentation I really don't see the problem. I'm using the following code.

```
function GetEllipsisString(Font: TFont; const Text: string; 
  Width: integer): String;
var
  DC: HDC;
  SaveFont: HFont;
  R: TRect;
begin
  DC := GetDC(0);
  try
    SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
    R := Rect (0, 0, Width-1, 0);
    Result := Text+'    ';
    Winapi.Windows.DrawtextW (DC, PChar(Result), Length(Result), R,
      DT_CALCRECT+DT_LEFT+DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS+DT_MODIFYSTRING);
    SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
  end;
end;
```

DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS just doesn't seem to do anything. I tried it with DT_END_ELLIPSIS and that gave me some result (see example). When I give the paramater "Text" a string with a backslash (\) in it, it does seem to set the ellipsis but the function ignores the rect measurements.

### Example

```
Text = 'This text has to many characters to fit.'
DT_END_ELLIPSIS returns 'This text has to m...'#0'characters to fit.    '
DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS returns 'This text has to many characters to fit.    '
```

Comment: The string you're printing isn't a path. What results were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting something like: "This text has ... charachters to fit." The documententation states: "For displayed text, replaces characters in the middle of the string with ellipses so that the result fits in the specified rectangle."

Comment: Paths are being shortened in between backslashes as far as I remember.

Comment: It works with strings like 'This\text has to many characters to\ fit.', and tries to preserve last backslash. MSDN keeps silent that this parameter doesn't work for arbitrary strings (w/o backslash)

Comment: @MBo: It's not "keeping silent". The name of the constant uses `PATH` for a reason - it's for making text containing file or directory names, thus the word **PATH**.

Comment: I did ownerdraw listbox with `DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS` and can confirm what it works OK. @TLama is absolutely correct, `DrawText` shortens middle **path component(s)**, preserving leading and trailing ones.

Comment: @Ken White: To silent for me... Sure I get that with using PATH it should be asumed to work on paths, but it isn't documented that way (only working on paths) and that misled me. I'll go on writing my own function then :) Thanks for the replies anyway.

Comment: I agree with Tupel's interpretation of the documentation, @Ken. The docs describe what the flag does ("replaces characters in the middle of the string with ellipses"), and then point out how that behavior is refined with the added presence of backslashes. If the flag doesn't work without backslashes, then the documentation is misleading, and I'd go so far as to say it's just wrong.

Comment: @Rob: I'd agree, except the docs for the flag also refer you to the other two ELLIPSIS flags, which are appropriate for text without backslashes. The term `PATH` in the flag (for anyone who understands what a DOS/Windows PATH is) seem be enough along with the discussion of backslashes in the description to clarify the use.

Comment: @Tupel Did you try `DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a procedure that draws a string with an ellipsis in the middle if the string is too wide for the given rect:

```
procedure DrawTextWithMiddleEllipsis(Canvas: TCanvas; Text: string; DrawRect:
   TRect; Flags: Integer);
var
  S, LastS: string;
  R: TRect;
  Sz: TSize;
  RectWidth, I: Integer;
begin
  S := Text;
  R := DrawRect;
  GetTextExtentPoint32(Canvas.Handle, S, Length(S), Sz);
  RectWidth := DrawRect.Right - DrawRect.Left;
  if Sz.cx > RectWidth then
  begin
    //The string is too wide. Need to cut it down with ellipsis
    //Start with the smallest possible truncated-and-ellipsis-modified string,
    //and expand until we have the biggest one that can fit
    S := '...';
    for I := 1 to Length(Text) div 2 do
    begin
      LastS := S;
      //Get the first I chars, then the ellipsis, then the last I chars
      S := Copy(Text, 1, I) + '...' + Copy(Text, Length(Text) - I + 1, I);
      GetTextExtentPoint32(Canvas.Handle, S, Length(S), Sz);
      if Sz.cx > RectWidth then
      begin
        DrawText(Canvas.Handle, LastS, Length(LastS), DrawRect, Flags);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end else
    //The string will fit in the width of the given rect, don't mess with it
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, S, Length(S), DrawRect, Flags);
end;
```

Here's an example of how its called (`PaintBox1` is a `TPaintBox`):

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  R: TRect;
begin
  S := 'This is extra long text that should overflow';
  R := PaintBox1.ClientRect;
  DrawTextWithMiddleEllipsis(PaintBox1.Canvas, S, R, DT_LEFT or DT_TOP);
end;
```

Comment: The question was why DrawText wasn't working as I expected. I already wrote my own function to do the work (which breaks at whole words). But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jthurman code

Advantages:
*simplified,
*more universal
*fixes a bug

Enjoy.

```
 { Takes a long string and truncates it in the middle. Example: '123...789'  }
 function GetEllipsisText(CONST s: string; Canvas: TCanvas; MaxWidth:    Integer; Flags: Integer= DT_LEFT or DT_TOP): string;
var
 NewStr, LastStr: string;
 TextSize: TSize;
 EllipsisSize: Integer;
begin
 NewStr := '...';
 EllipsisSize:= Canvas.TextWidth(NewStr);

 GetTextExtentPoint32(Canvas.Handle, s, Length(s), TextSize);
 if TextSize.cX > MaxWidth
 then
   //Start with the smallest possible truncated-and-ellipsis-modified string, and expand until we have the biggest one that can fit
   for VAR i:= 1 to Length(s) div 2 do
    begin
       LastStr := NewStr;
       NewStr := Copy(s, 1, I) + '...' + Copy(s, Length(s) - I + 1, I);   // Get the first I chars, then the ellipsis, then the last I chars
       GetTextExtentPoint32(Canvas.Handle, NewStr, Length(NewStr), TextSize);
       if TextSize.cx > (MaxWidth - EllipsisSize)
       then Exit(LastStr);
    end
else
   Result:= s;   //The string will fit in the width of the given rect, don't mess with it
end;
```